# Algorithm from a research paper

Tags: php, algorithm, pseudocode

I'm helping a friend in developing a project for our alma mater. And its based on [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330693703_An_Enhanced_Indoor_Positioning_Method_Based_on_Wi-Fi_RSS_Fingerprinting) paper.

So far 80% of the web app is finished except for the algorithm that needs to be implemented in the webapp. Inside this paper there is this algorithm that the proponents of the research used:

```
Algorithm 1 proposed method
1. Input data of fingerprints ,() and (
, ),  = 1, … ,  ;  = 1, … , ,  = 1, … , 
2. Input data of test ′
,
,  = 1, … ,  ;  = 1, … , 
3. for m=1:M do
4.    for l=1:  do
5.     for j=1:N do
6.      Calculate the Euclidian distance, ,(), between ′, and ,()
7.     end for
8.     Select the minimum (with respect to j) distance , among 
9.    end for
10. end for
11. Sort each column of the matrix ×
in ascending order, to obtain the matrix ×.
12. Store the ℎ(l = 1,…,L) element of each column of the matrix × in a vector.
13. Select the RP that has the minimum distance in this vector.
14. Output the coordinates of this RP as the estimated position.
```

The algorithm was converted to code by using MATLAB, but we are trying to use PHP with our project. The problem is we can't fully understand the psuedocode above. Can anyone help me somewhat "simplify" it to become more readable or understandable? Thank you so much!

This is the algorithm of from the paper:
[this is the screenshot of the algorithm that was used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAyif.png)

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot you provided, the algorithm is simply the Euclidean distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) for which the implementation can be found.

For example, here is one implementation in PHP https://supunkavinda.blog/php-euclidean-distance

You can also use the PHP-ML library which has already implemented it for you: https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/math/distance/

The authors then seem to have chosen the least Euclidean distance. Do you have any specific questions about the pseudocode? Hope this helps! Happy to answer follow-up questions in the comments.

Comment: thank you for the information!. Will look into the euclidian distance in PHP.
my question is. in your opinion is there a way to simplify that existing pseudocode? a much easier way to understand therefore easier to code in some way?